# php arrays to CSV

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have an array of arrays

```
$numbers= array(3) {
  [months]=>
    array(3) {
      ["1"]=>
      string(7) "Jan"
      ["2"]=>
      string(7) "Feb"
     ["3"]=>
     string(7) "Mar"
  }
[dates]=>
  array(3) {
    ["1"]=>
    string(7) "12th"
    ["2"]=>
    string(7) "19th"
    ["3"]=>
    string(7) "22nd"
 }
  [people]=>
  array(3) {
    ["1"]=>
    string(7) "Bill"
    ["2"]=>
    string(7) "Ted"
    ["3"]=>
    string(7) "Gary"
 }
 }
```

I want to write the contents of these arrays into a CSV file in the form of a table
so I get an output like:

```
 months,  dates, people 
 Jan,     12th,   Bill
 Feb,     19th,   Ted
 Mar,     22nd,   Gary
```

I want to try and put it directly from the array into the CSV in one move it it's possible but I can't find a way to do it without cutting it up.

Comment: [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) might help, but we're not going to write it for you. Personally, if the array is that small, I'd be inclined to use the SPL MultipleIterator to "transpose" the arrays

Comment: @MarkBaker He'd need to first transform his array.

Comment: Note: CSV stands for "Comma-separated values". if you're using CSV for a reason you might want to separate your values with commas OR just use a simple txt file

Comment: Since your arrays are the columns and the standard functions work by rows you probably need to work this manually through loops.

Comment: @MarkBaker the arrays aren't small the example is just to try and make sense of how I want the output to look rather than indicative of what it actually does.

Comment: Where do you get the data from? If it's from a database, you might be able to handle the transformation there

Comment: It's actually made by a series of calculations, I feel I may have missed a trick when assembling the data though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// transform the array
$keys = array_keys($numbers);
array_unshift($numbers, null);
$output = call_user_func_array('array_map', $numbers);
array_unshift($output, $keys);

// from php.net
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($output as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$headers = array();
foreach($numbers as $header => $data) {
    $mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($data));
    $headers[] = $header;
}

$fh = fopen('myfile.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fh, $headers);
foreach($mi as $values) {
    fputcsv($fh, $values);
}
fclose($fh);
```